# I define a C function named 'free': How to stop glibc's printf from using it?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, glibc, ubuntu-11.10, libc

My OS class assignment requires defining a C function named `free` which works differently from the libc `free`. (We're doing a memory allocator exercise.)

All of my code uses my own variant of `free`, so it's not a problem in my own code. However, when glibc uses `free` internally (e.g. for vprintf), it ends up using my `free` rather than its own.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (libc6 version 2.15-0ubuntu10). I heard it doesn't happen on other Ubuntu versions, and I wonder if I could get the other versions' behavior via some compile / link flag.

BTW, naming your own function `free` is not best practice, but let's say I don't have a choice :-)

Comment: Yes, C has a single namespace for global functions.   If you make a global function called `free` then either offer the same semantics (i.e. replace `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and `free`) or don't link with the standard C library.

Comment: Hi @JamesYoungman: the search terms "namespace" and "global functions" don't seem to uncover any relevant discussions. Specifically, namespaces are strongly associated with C++. Does GCC have some other lingo for "where all the global functions lurk"?

Comment: @Ilya: The fact that you can't find information on C namespaces is in fact the _proof_ of James's comment -- for top-level functions you've got `static` storage to confine the function to a single compilation unit or it is global and available to everything...

Comment: The course staff said "There's a supported version of Ubuntu. Install that instead." I'm trying to think what could possibly be different. Maybe it just coincidentally has a libc version whose printf is implemented with a built-in stack buffer that's big enough, so it just never triggers the problem?

Comment: You may wish to look into [other C libraries](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/FAQ.txt) to see how to write your own library and programs that don't use the standard glibc.

Comment: Using an alternative libc was never the goal of this rather humble OS class exercise :-) From `ld(1)`, the `-Bsymbolic` flag is a likely suspect -- that is, that my glibc is linked without it :/

Answer (score 2):

Do not name your function `free` if it has external linkage, the function name is reserved for as an identifier with external linkage.

> (C99, 7.1.3p1) "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."

Comment: Eh. The trouble is - the exercise is to develop a static library. This course so far leaves a lot to be desired quality-wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be replacing `free` and `malloc` with functions that do not behave identical to the standard ones, then you should probably *not* use any other "convenience" functions in the C library. Just stick to `read(2)` and `write(2)` for your IO -- or write your own wrappers around `read(2)` and `write(2)` to provide `getc(3)` and `printf(3)` kinds of convenience functions.

Comment: Thanks. It's not very convenient, though, and more important - nothing says it *has* to be this way. Whether to take my overrides or keep to its own is a decision.